# What is this line on my UITableView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uikit

I have a grouped table view. I've made tens of table views before, but I'm not sure what this line is:
[image]

Can anyone tell me what that is and how to remove it?

UPDATE:

I narrowed down the problem to the heightForRowAtIndexPath delegate method. Take a look at that below. Note that I need some of the rows to be taller:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViewLocal heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if(indexPath.section == 0 && (indexPath.row == 3 || indexPath.row == 4 || indexPath.row == 5))  {
        return tableViewLocal.rowHeight * 1.3; //If I remove the multiplier, it doesn't produce the line.
    }
    else
        return tableViewLocal.rowHeight;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the background. Try setting your tableView in code to

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: well it removes the line, but I really want to have the grouped stlye background. Using the code above will get me a white background essentially.

Comment: A bit hacky but if nothing else works you could put a UIView behind it with the backgroundcolor set like this: `view.backgroundColor = [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];`

Comment: I don't think it's hacky to put a UIView in behind your custom tableview cells. Sounds like a good idea.

Comment: Hmm strangely even that hacky way does not work... I'm guessing I might be doing something wrong in cellForRowAtIndexPath. Is that possible?

Comment: Hmm why does it not work? Do you get the same problem? Why don't you post some code?

Comment: Yes I got the same line on the same position. I have narrowed down the problem to the heightForRowAtIndexPath delegate method. I'll post the update on the question.